# How to display only the column has data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

[image]I'm making photo gallery. I have a question.

I would like to display data only 'images' column has data.
some of 'images' column has empty

Here is my current code.

```
public function pic_s1()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::where('images', "*.jpg")->orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->limit(20.)->get();
        return view('pic_s1',compact('images'));
    }
```

Could you teach me how to write query please?

Comment: If the field is empty, is it's value `NULL` or `""` (empty string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use whereNotNull like this:

```
public function pic_s1()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::whereNotNull('image')->where('image', '!=', '')->orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->limit(20.)->get();
        return view('pic_s1',compact('images'));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I tried your code but still I get other record. Could you look at my image what I just update? some records has image data. but some record's image column are empty( it's empy not null)

Comment: @Ranjeet you have just copied my answer

Comment: i have not copied, match your answer with my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write query like this

```
public function pic_s1()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::whereNotNull('images)->where('images','!=','')->orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->limit(20.)->get();
        return view('pic_s1',compact('images'));
    }
```